# Error command disabled through Anonymous user login in skype for business

Tags: javascript, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I want to login through Anonymous user in Skype for business i have followed this blog https://msdn.microsoft.com/Skype/WebSDK/docs/anonymousmeetingjoin

According to it we can login through generated URI. I have successfully login from the licence account and generated the URI **but when i am using the login through the anonymous user as defined i am getting error COMMAND DISABLED**

```
 NOTE:I HAVE ALSO SET ACCESS LEVEL TO EVERY ONE.
    "Error: CommandDisabled
        at Object.Exception (skype-web-sdk.js:20782)
        at BaseModel.pm_command [as signIn] (skype-web-sdk.js:21989)
        at Object.skype (Skype.html:100)
        at Skype.html:34
        at Event._invoke (skype-web-sdk.js:22136)
        at Event._fire (skype-web-sdk.js:22167)
        at Event._dequeue (skype-web-sdk.js:22184)
        at Function.ObserverImpl.on (skype-web-sdk.js:22259)
        at Function.observer (skype-web-sdk.js:22212)
        at Skype.html:30
        at onAPIReady (skype-web-sdk.js:157006)
        at <anonymous>`enter code here`"
```